# Create and use PowerShell object reference in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I need to instantiate a new object and pass it to a command input like this:

```
using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
{
    // Create configuration object
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(
        "$eap = New-EapConfiguration -UseWinlogonCredential");

    var cmd = new Command("Add-VpnConnection");
    // Set connection settings...
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(
        "EapConfigXmlStream", "$eap.EapConfigXmlStream"));

    pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
    pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

Result:

> Unable to convert "$eap.EapConfigXmlStream" in "System.Xml.XmlDocument" object type...

`$eap.EapConfigXmlStream` is interpreted as `string`, not as object reference

Any suggestion will be welcome

---

Edit:

@JohnB: This PS command works:

```
Set-VpnConnection -Name "MyVpnConnection"
    -EapConfigXmlStream (New-EapConfiguration -UseWinlogonCredential).EapConfigXmlStream
```

But this C# replacement does not works:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("EapConfigXmlStream",
    "(New-EapConfiguration -UseWinlogonCredential).EapConfigXmlStream"));
```

`(New-EapConfiguration -UseWinlogonCredential).EapConfigXmlStream` interpreted as `string`

Comment: i have a feeling that the EapConfigXmlStream param is expecting an XmlDocument - at least that is what I seem to understand from reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/add-vpnconnection?view=win10-ps

Comment: @JohnB: See my edit

Comment: tried to prefix with `[ref]`?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander: Same error, interpreted as `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work like this.
[CommandParameter(String, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.commandparameter.-ctor?view=pscore-6.2.0#System_Management_Automation_Runspaces_CommandParameter__ctor_System_String_System_Object_) expects an object, but you pass a string `"EapConfigXmlStream", "$eap.EapConfigXmlStream"`

Pass a PSObject instead:

```
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    Collection<PSObject> configXML;

    using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(
            "(New-EapConfiguration -UseWinlogonCredential).EapConfigXmlStream");
        configXML = pipeline.Invoke();
    }

    using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        var cmd = new Command("Add-VpnConnection");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(
            "EapConfigXmlStream", configXML[0]));
        pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
        pipeline.Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am trying it... Is it possible to keep the same pipeline and do not export object in C# context and import again in PS context ? Just create an object reference and use it (always stay in PS context)

Comment: not so sure, I did a quick test and it won't let me Invoke the pipeline twice. There will probably be a more elegant way.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. I exported `New-EapConfiguration` instead and use `cmd.Parameters.Add("EapConfigXmlStream", config.Properties["EapConfigXmlStream"].Value);`